# Big-Oh of nested loops, where inner loop depends on i*n and i*i of outer loop

Tags: big-o, nested-loops

What is the Big-Oh of the following nested loops:

```
sum=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<i*n;j++)
        sum+=i;
```

and

```
sum=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(j=0;j<i*i;j++)
        sum+=i;
```

I believe it's O(n^2), but all I've ever encountered is both loops using n as the test, so I don't know if O(n^2) is correct. If someone could verify my understanding or explain why I'm wrong, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: That question asked how to approximate in general. Here, I believe I know the approximation but I want to check my answer, and if it's wrong, understand why. That question doesn't have an answer for nested loops in particular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that they are both `O(n^3)`, since in both cases the inner loop is `O(n^2)` and the outer loop is `O(n)`. Granted they will run much much less than n^3 times, but if you graphed the runtime as a function of n, as n gets huge, you would find that the shape looks more like a cubic than a quadratic. My proof is that if you unroll the sum for the first one you get:

[image: equation1]

since you have n terms, each of which is `O(n^2)`, the whole thing is `O(n^3)`, albeit a very small `O(n^3)`.

For the second one:

[image]

which is even smaller than the first one, but still `O(n^3)`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks! So is the general rule for nested loops for Big-O, the inner * outer? From what I understand of your explanation and what my book said (it said it in a very confusing way, and thus why I wasn't able to understand the above 2 algorithms), that seems to be the case, but I just want to confirm. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! The general rule for big-O on loops is inner * outer. In equations you take the highest power of n and throw away everything else.

Comment: Just a quick additional question: is there a way to make the inner loop be O(n^3) w/o creating another loop? That is, with only 2 loops.

Comment: Sure, in the same way it's O(n^2) above: for( int j=0; j<n*n*n; j++)